# В чем может заключаться ошибка при загрузки изображения с галереи на сервер с помощью Retrofit?

Tags: android, post, retrofit, gallery

Пытаюсь отправить фото из галереи на сервер с помощью Retrofit. Но все время кидает в onError.

Интерфейс:

```
@Multipart
@POST("upload")
Call<UploadResponse> sendFile(@Part("file") RequestBody file);
```

Вот так вызываю галерею:

```
Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
            final Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(photoPickerIntent, "");
            startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, GALLERY_REQUEST);
```

В onActivityResult нахожу нужный файл:

```
Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();

        String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        android.database.Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        if (cursor == null) {
            return;
        }
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();

        File file = new File(filePath);
```

Оборачиваю в RequestBody и вызываю метод:

```
 RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file);
            presenter.sendUpload(body);
```

Метод выглядит так:

```
void sendUpload(RequestBody file){
        mService.sendFile(file).enqueue(new Callback<UploadResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<UploadResponse> call, @NonNull Response<UploadResponse> response) {
                if (response.body().getSuccess()) {
                    view.showResultUpload(response.body().getFile());
                } else {
                    view.showResultUpload(response.body().getMessage());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<UploadResponse> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
                Alerter.showMessage(App.getContext());
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Разрешение в манифесте прописал

Comment: Проблема может быть в файле, который вы пытаетесь отправить. Возможно, он не достался из галереи. Проверьте это

Comment: @ЮрийСПб посмотрел в логах filePath. Все нормально

Comment: Ну... Покажите тогда, что ли, логи ошибки